# Responsive web design - browser zoom breaks my layout

Tags: html, css, zooming, responsive

[zoomed-in 300%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjRR3.jpg)

I have issues when I zoom in with my layout, it's different than when I increase my width as I check through my responsive design

```
<header class="a u-section-padding">
        <nav class="navigation">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="navigation__logo" src="/img/logo-white.png" alt="logo">
                <ul class="navigation__main">
                    <li class="navigation__main-list"><a href="#">Food delivery</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation__main-list"><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation__main-list"><a href="#">Our cities</a></li>
                    <li class="navigation__main-list"><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="header">
            <h1 class="header__heading">Goodbye junk food. <br> Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
            <a class="header__buttons-1 u-button" href="#">I'm hungry</a>
            <a class="header__buttons-2 u-button" href="#">Show me more</a>
        </div>
    </header>

.header {
    &__heading {
        color: $color-white;
        font-size: $font-size-huge;
        font-weight: $font-weight-thick;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        
        @include respond(tab-land) {
            font-size: $font-size-medium;
        }

        @include respond(tab-port) {
            font-size: $font-size-small;
        }
    }
}

header {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,.8)), url(/css/img/hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 15%;
    @include respond(phone) {
        top: 50%;
    }
    &__heading {
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }
}
```

In other words, I have no idea how to make my website responsive to zoom. Any advice for a rookie here?

Comment: Not enough code, specific to your issue, has been provided to determine your problem.

Comment: Any idea of why that might happen though, any key points?

Comment: Maybe you're `float:left;` on `.header`, and that's just a margin making it look like it's not a total overlap?????????

Comment: I added some more code.. note that header is the element and .header is a class within that element owo

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.
Your header is position: absolute;
Is your first issue. Position absolute floats above other divs or around a relative parent.
Also in responsive design we do mobile first. min-width rather than max width. 
My advice would be completly start this again.
Make a section called banner. that would have your background image in.
Inside the banner make a div called content. That will have your two buttons in.
above that section make your header, Position absolute if you must.
Make it width: 100%; and display: flex; Work from there.

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty much it. Not a big fan of position absolute anymore. Thanks a lot chap!